# Please explain Java ^ operator with examples

Tags: java

What is the difference between:

```
if ((x <= 19 & x >= 13) ^ (y <= 19 & y >= 13))
{
    System.out.print(true);
}
else
{
    System.out.print(false);
}
```

and

```
if (x <= 19 && x >= 13 || y <= 19 && y >= 13)
{
    System.out.print(true);
}
else
{
    System.out.print(false);
}
```

Could you please explain me in detail the operator `^` ?. Please provide some examples.

Comment: This question is answered in the documentation.

Comment: It is amazing what one can find with a quick [search on Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+%5E+operator&oq=java+%5E+operator&aqs=chrome.0.0l6.4086j1j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8).

Comment: `^` stands for XOR.  That means that if you did `a ^ b`, for this to be true, either `a` is true or `b` is true, but not both.  Also, if both `a` and `b` were false, this would also be false.  XOR stands for Exclusive OR.  Check out XOR for more details: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or .  Use that and figure out what the `if` statements do!

Comment: Sorry dude. You've got to do your own homework assignments.

Comment: @rayryeng Ok I do understand that it means XOR and if both are false the result is false, but what is the difference between ^ and || ? || means OR? x || y for this to be true either x is true or b but not both?

Comment: `x || y` is logical OR.  That means either `x` or `y` needs to be true for the statement to be true.  Both `x` and `y` can be true for the statement to be true as well.  The core difference between XOR and OR is when both `x` and `y` are true.  XOR has its output to be false while OR is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`^` condition operator is the `XOR` in more mathematic terms, which stand from `Exclusive or`. (see [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or))
So the XOR to return true, your left hand side condition must be different from the right hand side condition otherwise is false.

e.g your condition if ((x <= 19 & x >= 13) ^ (y <= 19 & y >= 13)) will return **true** only in these two cases:

1) (x <= 19 & x >= 13) is **true** and (y <= 19 & y >= 13) is **false**

2) (x <= 19 & x >= 13) is **false** and (y <= 19 & y >= 13) is **true**

And will return **false** only in these two cases:

1) (x <= 19 & x >= 13) is **true** and (y <= 19 & y >= 13) is **true**

2) (x <= 19 & x >= 13) is **false** and (y <= 19 & y >= 13) is **false**

This will also be useful (is available and in the above link I provide for you)
[image]

Comment: You're too nice.  You should have let the OP figure it out on their own!

Comment: Thank you very much, I understand it now. 

If I use OR the truth table changes to: T or T = T ... etc

Comment: You can click the tick button to set the question as answered. @rayryeng I didn't even realise that was homework, I thought that is a question from a newbie in the Java programming.

Comment: @Dr.Programmer - Neither did I at first.  Once I read it carefully, I realized that it was.  If the OP were to restructure it so that it didn't sound like homework, I would have been more inclined to answer.  Either way, you care and that counts!

Comment: Again, it is not homework. We haven't arrived to the operator ^ yet. I just want to practice some examples!! I swear..